# How to use database view with jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2

I have created views in a DB2 data base and i'm trying to get the data from those views with jpa 2.0 but when i run ma server i have this :

```
May 18, 2017 6:24:34 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
May 18, 2017 6:24:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 18, 2017 6:24:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 18, 2017 6:24:34 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
May 18, 2017 6:24:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: dossier
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: provision
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: dossier
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: provision
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: dossier
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: provision
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table dossier (num_dossier varchar(255) not null, nature varchar(255), num_cheque varchar(255), patente varchar(255), personne varchar(255), primary key (num_dossier))
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: [SQL0204] FNAC de type *LIB dans QSYS non trouvé.
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table provision (id varchar(255) not null, annee integer not null, imp_capital integer not null, imp_int_ht integer not null, imp_int_ttc integer not null, mois integer not null, mte_prov_rest integer not null, nbr_imp integer not null, typ_dossier varchar(255), dossier varchar(255), primary key (id))
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: [SQL0204] FNAC de type *LIB dans QSYS non trouvé.
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table provision add constraint FK_2lk1jgv8il1kjgiv25veiiy6m foreign key (dossier) references dossier
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: [SQL0204] PROVISION de type *FILE dans FNAC non trouvé.
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1950 ms
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8 ( 20140814-1418 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8@13507) for context '/FNACStatistic'
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/FNACStatistic/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/11  config=null
May 18, 2017 6:24:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3030 ms
```

```html
@Entity
public class Provision implements Serializable {


 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @Getter
 private String id;
 @Getter
 private int annee;
 @Getter
 private int mois;
 @Getter 
 private int mteProvRest;
 @Getter 
 private int impCapital;
 @Getter 
 private int impIntHt;
 @Getter 
 private int impIntTtc;
 @Getter 
 private String typDossier;
 @Getter
 private int nbrImp;
 
 
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="dossier")
 @Getter 
 private Dossier dossier;
```

```html
@Entity
public class Dossier implements Serializable  {

 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
 @Id
 @Getter
 private String numDossier;
 @Getter 
 private String personne;
 @Getter 
 private String numCheque;
 @Getter 
 private String nature;
 @Getter @Setter
 private String patente;
```

I know that JPA deal with database view the same as a table but i couldn't figure out where the probleme come from .

Comment: @Billy Forst i don't understand what do you mean by tagging ? the issu is not present when i use Postgres , it appears when i switch to AS400 db2

Comment: you see those little words below your post "java", "hibernate", "jpa" etc? Those are tags. They allow people who know a bit about those things to find your question. You hadn't added "hibernate", so I did, and since your problem is specific to Hibernate it needs to be there or you won't attract any attention. No idea what you are talking about with Postgres

Comment: okey thks i understand what you mean now , i thaugh wrong and i was just explaining my probleme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found the source of the probleme: i did forget to specify the name of the database on the connexion url. so it works now

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate configuration (hbm2ddl: update) is trying to create your view.
Is the entity mapping the view correctly? (same view-name, same fields? )

In addition, you should add @Immutable on your class. This will prevent any update. (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html)

Comment: Yes i have the view-name and the same fields . i 'll try to do that thnk you

Comment: I've added immutable to my classes but it still show me the same thing